# jQuery - select tag - get attribute of the selected element

Tags: jquery, select, attributes

Is there a way of getting the attribute - such as 'rel' from the selected option of the 'select' tag - i.e.?

```
<select name="menu" id="menu">
    <option value="1" rel="123">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" rel="124">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just use the `:selected` filter.

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/ECAea/

```
$('#menu').change(function(){
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').attr('rel'));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

with jQuery

```
$('#menu option:selected').attr('rel');
```

with javascript

```
var sel = document.getElementById('menu');
var option = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
var rel = option.getAttribute('rel');
```

demo with both versions at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/WLFmv/

Comment: This one also works very well - thank you. The accepted answer was a bit more flexible as it doesn't take the id of the element - it simply uses $(this) to refer to the trigger element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.attr("attributeName")` to get the value of attributes. See [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

To find the selected option you can use `$('#menu option[selected=true]')` or similar.

Comment: I tried it before - but it doesn't seem to get the attribute value for some reason.