# Get specific attribute from select option bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, attributes

i don't have find into documentation how to grab a specific attributed specified from a `<select>` input...

for example i have

```
<select id="part_anat" name="part_anat" class="bs-select form-control">
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="1">text2</option>
    <option value="1.4">text3</option>
    <option value="1.4">text4</option>
    <option value="1.8">test5</option>
    <option value="1">test6</option>
    <option value="1">test7</option>
    <option value="1.5">test8</option>
    <option value="1.6">test9</option>
</select>
```

now i use: `$('#part_anat').get()[0].selectedOptions[0].attributes[0].value`
but i am finding a *similar shortcut to get correctly value*... there are other method?

EDIT:
`$('#part_anat').find(':selected')[0].value`
 or
`$('#part_anat').find('option:selected').val()`
 or
`$('#part_anat').find('option:selected').attr('value')`
 this is my solutions, but i would know another thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i must use value, selected from navigator, into a operation on submit()...

Comment: No you don't - the right value will be submitted when you submit the form. I suggest you read a bit about HTML forms.

Comment: now i have try it and work... see here [link](http://www.bootply.com/130388) and on change of option alert you value ;)

Comment: reference: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5947669/2517327)